# How to create a library inside another library in Angular?

Tags: angular, nrwl

This should be a very trivial thing, because I don't find any reference about this or I don't know where and how to look for it. Let's say I have a scoped library `core`

`@myscope/core`

Now in this library I have a folder `auth` for authentication workflow.

When I want to use library in my `App` I import it using this:

`import {AuthService} from @myscope/core`

What I want to achieve, is to create a `sub-library` so I can use like that:

`import {AuthService} from @myscope/core/auth`

I know this is possible by creating a new path in the `tsconfig`, but I don't see that as a good resolution, because once I create a package out of this library, this path won't be delivered.

What is the best way to go?

Comment: if `@myscope/core` is the main entry point for the public api of your lib, is there any reason that you are looking to expose secondary entry points?

Comment: btw, how was your library created? nrwl workspace? angular-cli lib?

Comment: the reason is that I'm exposing the state (ngrx reducers) of my auth library which belongs to core. for example: `@angular/http` and `@angular/http/common`. the library is in a nrwl workspace.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question but I managed to solve this using secondary entry points 
https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/secondary-entrypoints.md

For your setup, the structure of your library should look like this..

```
myscope
├── src
|   ├── public_api.ts
|   └── *.ts
├── ng-package.json
├── package.json
└── auth
    ├── src
    |   ├── public_api.ts
    |   └── *.ts
    └── ng-package.json
```

Note that in the documentation it says that you can just use package.json but that didn't work for me, I had to create another ng-package.json as describe in the article as ***Alternative to package.json***

Inside your ng-package.json in the auth directory, you would need to put something like this

```
{
    "lib": {
        "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts"
    }
}
```

and that should be all you need, that worked for me

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Good question. With Angular 6, I tried these commands:

```
ng new sublibs
cd sublibs
ng generate library @myscope/core
ng generate library @myscope/core/auth
Project name "@myscope/core/auth" is invalid.
```

As you can see, it didn't work. But I didn't give up. I opened VS Code and copied sublibs/projects/myscope/core and pasted it inside itself then renamed sublibs/projects/myscope/core/core to sublibs/projects/myscope/core/auth. Then I went through all of the files in sublibs/projects/myscope/core/auth and modified the paths and names everywhere. This was mostly adding /auth or another ../ where appropriate. Then I renamed all of the files in sublibs/projects/myscope/core/auth/src/lib and changed the class names that start with Core so that they start with Auth. I didn't forget to change the package.json in sublibs/projects/myscope/core/auth and to add core/auth in angular.json by copying and pasting core and modifying it. After I was satisfied everything was renamed and changed appropriately, I entered the command:

```
ng build @myscope/auth
```

Here is the output:

```
Robert@ROBERT-PC MINGW64 /d/Users/Robert/robertbrower.technologies/customers/robertbrower.technologies/sublibs
$ ng build @myscope/core
Building Angular Package
Building entry point '@myscope/core'
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
Bundling to FESM2015
Bundling to FESM5
Bundling to UMD
Minifying UMD bundle
Copying declaration files
Writing package metadata
Removing scripts section in package.json as it's considered a potential security vulnerability.
Built @myscope/core
Building entry point '@myscope/core/auth'
Compiling TypeScript sources through ngc
Bundling to FESM2015
Bundling to FESM5
Bundling to UMD
Minifying UMD bundle
Copying declaration files
Writing package metadata
Removing scripts section in package.json as it's considered a potential security vulnerability.
Built @myscope/core/auth
Built Angular Package!
 - from: D:\Users\Robert\robertbrower.technologies\customers\robertbrower.technologies\sublibs\projects\myscope\core
 - to:   D:\Users\Robert\robertbrower.technologies\customers\robertbrower.technologies\sublibs\dist\myscope\core

Robert@ROBERT-PC MINGW64 /d/Users/Robert/robertbrower.technologies/customers/robertbrower.technologies/sublibs
$
```

Then I was able to enter this command:

```
ng generate application my-app
```

After that I was able to modify my-app's app.module like this:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { CoreModule } from '@myscope/core';
import { AuthModule } from '@myscope/core/auth';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    AuthModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Then I built my-app:

```
ng build my-app
```

And I received this output:

```
Robert@ROBERT-PC MINGW64 /d/Users/Robert/robertbrower.technologies/customers/robertbrower.technologies/sublibs
$ ng build my-app

Date: 2018-11-22T22:43:33.834Z
Hash: b686631b6cb537b9519c
Time: 10255ms
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 20.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 249 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.22 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 16.7 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 3.01 MB [initial] [rendered]

Robert@ROBERT-PC MINGW64 /d/Users/Robert/robertbrower.technologies/customers/robertbrower.technologies/sublibs
$
```

So while I do not know how to use the Angular CLI to achieve this, I was able to do it manually.

See the repo: https://github.com/robertbrower-technologies/sublibs

Comment: I think the main problem here you always gonna have problems if the cli changes and you'll have to update everytime things by hand. this is a workaround more than a real solution.I wonder how angular team does this.

Comment: Any luck finding a CLI solution to do this? Even angular repo has this structure. They must have something under the hood.. :)